# Is there any significance to the zfs USERDATA dataset suffix?

Tags: 22.04, zfs

I recently installed 22.04. My home directory is on the zfs dataset `rpool/USERDATA/me_xxxxxx` (where `xxxxxx` *seems* to be a random-ish string?). The same suffix is used for the root user's dataset.

Is there any significance to this suffix? Is there any repercussions if I change the dataset name?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for a week (while I script a pop_os -> ZFS single root -> LUKS -> systemd-coot setup). And, zero documentation on this "suffix" from OpenZFS.

I am pretty sure it is for importing the pool onto another machine - that may already have an `rpool/BOOT`.  Having a unique suffix helps identify which dataset you are working on:

(a completely made up list, for demostrations)

```
# zfs list
NAME                              USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                             476K  16.5G    21K  
rpool/ROOT_abc123                 476K  16.5G    21K  /
rpool/DATASET_abc123               18K  16.5G    21K  
rpool/DATASET_abc123/root          18K  16.5G    21K  /root
broken_pool/                       18K  33.0G    18K  /broken_pool/
broken_pool/ROOT_xyz789            18K  33.0G    18K  /broken_pool/root
broken_pool/DATASET_xyz789         18K  33.0G    21K  
broken_pool/DATASET_xyz789/root    18K  33.0G    21K  /root
```

Also, it helps identify the snapshots - in a remote backup with other ROOT datasets.

Given, the root pool name also provides the identify.  However, consider multiple pve servers named pve01 and pve02, which you are replicating, backing up, etc.

```
pve01/rpool/ROOT/
pve07/rpool/ROOT/
```

But with identifiers, it helps prevent type-os.

```
pve01/rpool/ROOT_abc123/
pve07/rpool/ROOT_xyz789/
```

---

On a personal note, I do not use any suffixes for my laptops, tablets, desktops, nor 5 servers - all backing up to the same remote backup server.  At times, it's been challenging to type *exactly* the right server name to get the right dataset.  Having suffixes would prevent more type-os - however, at the cost of copying a lot more!

Also, searching for snapshots makes it much easier to find exactly the dataset you want.

Comment: You may well be entirely correct, but I can't even imagine how anyone could possibly consider this a good idea.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea, and I said I don't use them in my homelab.  I was providing an answer to your question as to *why*.  :)

Comment: No, not meaning you, you're just the messenger. It's just my commentary on whoever came up with this.

Comment: Btw, for my homelab I use `pm1725.pool/apollo/root/` and `/pm1725.pool/apollo/home/eric` where `pm1725.pool` is the type of drives I'm using in the pool, `apollo` is the name of the server.  And you have `root` for the filesystem and `home` to match users home directory.  This allows me to import the pool into a new machine if I need to, without having to worry about the machine name (nor suffix!).